# How do you go about making an e-commerce system support multilingual

Tags: architecture, e-commerce, system, multilingual

We have an e-commerce system that is supporting dynamic content coming from multiple sources. The system is written in Java and uses postgreSQL as the DB.

I am looking at how we should go about making the system support multiple languages.

I know technically how this can be done, but what would the steps be.

Which areas would you start making multilinugual? will it be first the content and the supporting user inputs?

Does anyone know of any good white papers regarding this subject?

Any help would be really appreciative.

Comment: In an ecommerce site? I'd start with the billing / purchase page workflows. Without those being available in a language, there's not much point in users of that language seeing your product details, is there?

Answer (score 0):

> Which areas would you start making multilingual?

This should come from the business requirements, but I'd have thought the product details should be multilingual as a bare minimum.

> Will it be first the content and the supporting user inputs?

The content would surely be one of the first areas to be multilingual.

Given the potential for disruption I'd start with the URLs - they really need to be multilingual for SEO.

Comment: The thing is, I am trying to support business to make the right decision. The way I see they have phased out the development is having some concerns with me. I am looking at white papers on how to convert an existing system to multilingual. It's not just translation but globalization and localization that we need to look at as well.

Comment: If you have to lead, then I suggest you start with the product details so they are actually found by other search engines in the relevant languages. And as mentioned the URL is part of that change, and it is a good idea to start with the URLs.